# Getting number of rows from two tables and placing it in a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am simply trying to get the number of rows from two tables and trying to place it in a PHP variable. The two tables involved are:

- `flagged_posts`: Which has 3 rows.
- `flagged_comments`: Which has 1 row.

The answer I am expecting to be echo'd is `4`, but the number being echo's with the query below is `1`.

```
$all_flagged_posts = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT sum(cnt) 
                                                FROM 
                                                (
                                                SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM flagged_comments
                                                UNION all 
                                                SELECT count(*) FROM flagged_posts
                                                ) tmp");

$num_of_total_flagged_posts = mysqli_num_rows ($all_flagged_posts);
echo $num_of_total_flagged_posts;
```

Comment: You need just `+=mysali_num.... etc` and put the string before loop `num_of_total...etc = 0` sorry you var long and I write by phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are summarizing number of rows from only one of tables.
 
`SELECT sum(cnt)` sums up the number of rows from the `flagged_comments` table (as `cnt` is an alias for that table)
Change your query as shown below (without using unnecessary `union all`):

```
$all_flagged_posts = mysqli_query($connect," SELECT 
       ((SELECT count(*) FROM flagged_comments )
       + 
       (SELECT count(*) FROM flagged_posts)) as summa");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($connect, $all_flagged_posts);
echo $row['summa'];
```

Comment: And you still want me to follow this approach when I have changed my query to the one specified by you above?     `$num_of_total_flagged_posts = mysqli_num_rows ($all_flagged_posts);
echo $num_of_total_flagged_posts;`? ... I have changed my query to the above, and kept everything else the same, still returns the value of `1`. Also, what is `summa`? first time I have came across this.

Comment: `"And you still want me to follow this approach "` - I didn't compel you to follow, I'm suggesting working solution(tested on my local database). `Also, what is summa? ` - `summa` is an alias for convenient output(if you didn't know)

Comment: Basically, is this what you want me to run to get output of `4`:  `$all_flagged_posts = mysqli_query ($connect, " SELECT 
               ((SELECT count(*) FROM flagged_comments )
               + 
               (SELECT count(*) FROM flagged_posts)) as summa");
    $num_of_total_flagged_posts = mysqli_num_rows ($all_flagged_posts);
 echo $num_of_total_flagged_posts;`?

Comment: that's not what I want. (You have to fetch the summarized value) See my update

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_num_rows` returns **number of rows**. So, when you execute your query result is **one** row with value `4`.

You should `fetch` result data and check `sum(cnt)` field:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all_flagged_posts);
print_r($row);  // check the keys and get the value you need
```